# SSL Configuration for Java to connect WAS MQ using BUS

Tags: java, ssl, jms, websphere

For connecting to WAS MQ using **Bus**, TransportProviderChain and ProviderEndpoints using SSL, currently  SSL properties using javax.net.ssl.* keyStore and trustSore are provided. 
However this clashes with a different set of keyStore and trustStore for Kafka **Schema registry** which also accepts the ssl properties using only javax.net.ssl.* properties.

As far as I know we have to use `com.ibm.websphere.sib.api.jms.JmsConnectionFactory` which does not have a way of adding SSLSocketFactory.

Now the question is, is there a way of providing SSL properties to JmsConnectionFactory using something such as SSLSocketFactory.

Comment: Bus? Do you mean sibus? Are you using MQLink?

Comment: yes it means SIBUS. Yes using ip:port:BootstrapSecureMessaging in application properties.